# How adobe flex stores user credentials on browser

Tags: apache-flex, cookies, passwords

I have a http url that asks for user name and password. The client side is built using Adobe Flex. The user name /password dialog box is the default one serviced by MS windows, not a custom one.

When I hit the url, it should ask me for a password, but by default it is taking a stored password from somewhere(which is an old outdated one).

Even after clearing the cookies, it still does not prompt me for a password, it keeps picking up the old password and login fails.

Where in adobe flex are passwords stored on the browser? Even logging off and relog in does not help.

It is IE8, what settings should I check?

Comment: When you say "The user name /password dialog box is the default one serviced by MS windows", do you mean the login prompt that you might see for something such as RDP?  I think you are going to have to explain the actual setup a little more because I can't imagine how this is happening.  I've used username/password and AD/SSO integration for authentication and have never had this issue.

Comment: Thanks, it was dues to a firewall problem.